# hexo s is ok while hexo g -d shows File not found

Tags: git, hexo

Thanks for reading my question in advance.
Last year I build my website by [Hexo][1],But later I changed a new computer and the setting folder is missing. So I tried to deploy again in the new computer.

Comment: Did you select master for publication? (as in https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)

Comment: @VonC Yes, as the  _config.yml file shows that deploy branch: master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Via this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055025/git-ignore-public-index-html)I find out that there is a global ignore file :

```
 /Users/judy/.gitignore_global
```

Clean it and this problem solved.

Comment: So I did help in the end ;) +1

Comment: @VonC  Thank you very much!!