# Git ignore public/index.html

Tags: git, reactjs, github, create-react-app

Thanks for reading my question in advance.The Git always ignores the public/index.html file.
I created a project by create-react-app and it works successfully.
But when I push it to Github, the public/index.html was lost.
[Take this project for example.](https://github.com/pavilion2t/howtographql)
the .gitignore is:

```
# See https://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

I tried to new another index.html and commit/push it again.But it shows nothing to commit. How can I fix this problem?  The terminal looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You may have other gitignore files. Places to look for is described in https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to use whan a file is not added/committed is:

```
git check-ignore -v -- public/index.html
```

That will tell you if there is *any* gitignore/exclude/`core.excludesfile` file with an ignore rule.

Typically, an IDE can add its own ignore rules in a global gitignore file.